# How to Create Stand alone Process Engine in Eclipse for Activiti

Tags: eclipse, h2, activiti

Eclipse: Oxygen.1 (4.7.1)

H2: 1.3.176

Activiti: 6.0.0

I'm new in Activiti and I just want to run a process Not using the in-memory database, but switched to (createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration) inorder to the default standalone H2 database.
Regarding this, I have 2 questions:

1. What is the exact difference between createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration and createStandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration for process engine configuration.
2. While I want to run a simple project, it throws some exception.

### Sample Project:

```
public static void startBookOrder1() {
ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration
.createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration()
.buildProcessEngine(); 

RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
IdentityService identityService = processEngine.getIdentityService();
TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService(); 

repositoryService.createDeployment()
.addClasspathResource("bookorder.bpmn20.xml")
.deploy();

List<Task> availableTaskList = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskName("Work on order").list();
for (Task task : availableTaskList) {
taskService.complete(task.getId());
} 

Map<String, Object> variableMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
variableMap.put("isbn", "123456");
identityService.setAuthenticatedUserId("kermit");
ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(
"bookorder", variableMap);
assertNotNull(processInstance.getId());
List<Task> taskList = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskName("Work on order").list();
assertEquals(1, taskList.size());
System.out.println("found task " + taskList.get(0).getName());
System.out.println("found task " );
}
```

### Exceptions

```
Exception in thread "main" org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: no activiti tables in db. set <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" to value="true" or value="create-drop" (use create-drop for testing only!) in bean processEngineConfiguration in activiti.cfg.xml for automatic schema creation
at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.dbSchemaCheckVersion(DbSqlSession.java:989)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.performSchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild(DbSqlSession.java:1470)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.execute(SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.java:25)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl.<init>(ProcessEngineImpl.java:77)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:427)
at BookOrderTest.startBookOrder1(BookOrderTest.java:33)
at BookOrderTest.main(BookOrderTest.java:26)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database. Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "ACT_GE_PROPERTY" not found; SQL statement:
select VALUE_ from ACT_GE_PROPERTY where NAME_ = 'schema.version' [42102-176]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:178)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:154)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5213)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1220)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1859)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1968)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1853)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1674)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1662)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:434)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:306)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:278)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:243)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:442)
at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:265)
at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:160)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
### The error may exist in org/activiti/db/mapping/entity/Property.xml
### The error may involve org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.PropertyEntity.selectDbSchemaVersion
### The error occurred while executing a query
### SQL: select VALUE_ from ACT_GE_PROPERTY where NAME_ = 'schema.version'
### Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "ACT_GE_PROPERTY" not found; SQL statement:
select VALUE_ from ACT_GE_PROPERTY where NAME_ = 'schema.version' [42102-176]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:178)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:154)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5213)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1220)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1859)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1968)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1853)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1674)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1662)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:434)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:306)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:278)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:243)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:442)
at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:265)
at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:160)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:107)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:98)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:62)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:57)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.getDbVersion(DbSqlSession.java:1011)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.dbSchemaCheckVersion(DbSqlSession.java:967)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "ACT_GE_PROPERTY" not found; SQL statement:
select VALUE_ from ACT_GE_PROPERTY where NAME_ = 'schema.version' [42102-176]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:178)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:154)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5213)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1220)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1859)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1968)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1853)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1674)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1662)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:434)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:306)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:278)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:243)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:442)
at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:265)
at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:160)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:567)
at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.prepare(CommandRemote.java:67)
at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.<init>(CommandRemote.java:46)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.prepareCommand(SessionRemote.java:439)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1109)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:74)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:264)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledConnection.invoke(PooledConnection.java:245)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.instantiateStatement(PreparedStatementHandler.java:72)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.BaseStatementHandler.prepare(BaseStatementHandler.java:82)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.prepare(RoutingStatementHandler.java:54)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:70)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:56)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:259)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:132)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:105)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:81)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:104)
... 15 more
```

What I did for H2 database:
1. I copied the h2-1.3.176.jar file into activiti libreries folder.
2. I have created a file 'activiti.cfg.xml' in this direction of my project : /test/resources. it contains the below data:

### activiti.cfg.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration" >
    <!-- Database configurations -->
    <property name="databaseType" value="h2" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/activiti" />
    <property name="jdbcDriver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUsername" value="sa" />
    <property name="jdbcPassword" value="sa" />
    <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="create-drop" />
  </bean>
  
</beans>
```

Thank you so much for any helping.

Answer (score 0):

The errors indicate the database tables were not created.
Check your DB and confirm they were created.
Also, try to manually create the tables (using the provided sql files) and see if that works.
None of this should be necessary, but stranger things have happened.